My URL is not calling the function of the controller Yii2
I have a function name import in the contact controller. The issue is that when I am trying to make a call to the function with https://example.org/contact/import, the import function is not executing. It shows me 403 error. The other functions of the controller like create is working fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Here is my controller code:
    <?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Contact;

class ContactController extends Controller
{

    protected function newmodel()
    {
        return new Contact();
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $objModel = $this->newmodel();        
        $objReflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($objModel);
        $objModel->load([$objReflectionClass->getShortName() => Yii::$app->request->get()]);
        $strView = 'create';
        if (!file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/views/' . strtolower($objReflectionClass->getShortName()) . '/create.php'))
        {
            // default
            $strView = '/default/create';
        }

        return $this->render($strView, [
            'objModel' => $objModel,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionImport()
    {
        die("In import function");
        
    }
}

Here is the routes rules
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'gii'=>'gii/default/login',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
            'debug/<controller>/<action>' => 'debug/<controller>/<action>',
            '' => 'site/index',
            'forgotpassword' => 'site/forgotpassword',

            '<action:(contact|login|logout)>' => 'site/<action>',
            '<action:(contact|login|logout)>/*' => 'site/<action>',

            '<controller:\w+>/'=>'<controller>/index',

            '<controller:\w+>/<intId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/view/<intId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',

            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<intId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],

If the create function is working then I believe import function should also work. Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong.
Many Thanks!
I tried to manually I add the static route rule for my url but that was not working.
Here is how I added that rule
   'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'gii'=>'gii/default/login',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
            'debug/<controller>/<action>' => 'debug/<controller>/<action>',
            '' => 'site/index',
            'forgotpassword' => 'site/forgotpassword',

            '<action:(contact|login|logout)>' => 'site/<action>',
            '<action:(contact|login|logout)>/*' => 'site/<action>',

            '<controller:\w+>/'=>'<controller>/index',

            '<controller:\w+>/<intId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/view/<intId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',

            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<intId:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            'ContactController/actionImport' => 'contact/import',
        ],
    ],

Update
here is the screenshot of what I am getting when open https://example.org/contact/import


Could you tell me what response you have when running contact/import ?
When you declare a route, the left argument (key) is the pattern your user use to access your function, the right being where is your function so your static route is incorrect.

@SamHuffman Thank you for looking at it. I updated my question above with a screenshot of 404 page which I am getting when I open https://example.org/contact/import url

The screenshot you gave mentions a 403 not a 404.

My bad. Updated error code in my question above.

This rule '<action:(contact|login|logout)>/*' => 'site/<action>', makes your contact/import request go to contact action in site controller instead of your contact controller. The 403 error might be result of some behavior or the logic inside your site/contact action.

@MichalHynčica Thank you for looking at my issue. I tried changing controller name. Renamed controller from contact to ImportcontactsController and function name actionImport. The route rule defined as 'importcontacts/import' => 'ImportcontactsController/actionImport' under urlManager. When trying to execute the function actionImport from url https://example.org/importcontacts/import, still giving me 403 error screen

The basic syntax for rules is 'path/in/url' => 'controller-id/action-id'. The controller ID for ImportcontactsController will be importcontacts, the action id for actionImport will be import. So correct rule will be 'importcontacts/import' => 'importcontacts/import'. But you don't need to explicitly specify that rule, because rule '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>' does the same thing (just more generic) as long as your url path doesn't match any previous rule.

About error 403. As I said in previous comment it might be caused by some behavior. But it's impossible to tell exact cause with only the code you've posted in your question.
